# dotnetscorm-error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified

Tags: asp.net

I am receiving this error after installing dotnetscorm LMS.
The installation finishes with no problem. I set the connection string to the (local) server with a username and password that have connect permission and enough privileges for accessing the data. then when trying to open default page I receive this error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
```

Well, I am sure there is no problem with the connection and remote aconnection is allowed. Funny thing is when I change the username or password or change a permission on the database objects it complains about low permissions so obviously server is accessible.
What should I do? By the way I know that dotnetscorm is old and there are open source platforms in python but I am a dotnet guy!

Comment: No, it is a sql connection issue

Comment: Ok, so can you tell me how to solve it?

Comment: Please let us know connection string format in web.config. Simple thing to test is create DSN and test connectionstring first.

Comment: this is the connection string:     <add name="DotNetSCORMDB" connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=DotNetSCORM;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=dns-user;Password=dns-password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to find the problem:
Somewhere in my machine configuration (and I don't care where) there is a LocalSqlServer connection and I just needed to remove it in my own connectionstrings section.

```
<connectionStrings>
<remove name="LocalSqlServer"/>
<!-- SQL Server Native Client Connection String -->
<add name="DotNetSCORMDB" connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=DotNetSCORM;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=dns-user;Password=dnspassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
<add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=DotNetSCORM;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=dns-user;Password=dnspassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```